# Java dynamically add checkboxes on run time

Tags: java

I have my project that will display checkboxes through for loop. My problem is, I have my JFrame, everytime I run it, checkboxes are in another Window. What I want is to display it on my JFrame.. Anybody who has an idea regarding to my problem?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY6Sw.png

Here's my code on adding checkboxes dynamically:

```
    String title = (args.length == 0 ? "CheckBox Sample" : args[0]);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test");
    panel.setBorder(border);

    javax.swing.JCheckBox[] jCheckboxArray;

    int CheckBoxNumber = 5;
    jCheckboxArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[CheckBoxNumber];
    for(int x = 0; x < CheckBoxNumber ; x++) {
        jCheckboxArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jCheckboxArray[x].setText("CheckBox " + x);
        panel.add(jCheckboxArray[x]);
    }

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here's my full code:

```
package Employees;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class Workers extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

    public Workers() {
        initComponents();
        DoConnect();
    }
    public void DoConnect(){
        try{
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
            String uName = "cepe";
            String uPass = "admin";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            rs.next();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            textID.setText(id);
            textFirstName.setText(first);
            textLastName.setText(last);
            textJobTitle.setText(job);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        textID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textFirstName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textLastName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textJobTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Job Title:");

        jButton1.setText("First");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Previous");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Next");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Last");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textID))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(textFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(textLastName))
                            .addComponent(textJobTitle)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(0, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(textLastName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textFirstName)
                    .addComponent(textID))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(textJobTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addGap(0, 13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            if(rs.next()){
                int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
                String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
                String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
                String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
                String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

                textID.setText(id);
                textFirstName.setText(first);
                textLastName.setText(last);
                textJobTitle.setText(job);
            }
            else{
                rs.previous();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            if(rs.previous()){
                int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
                String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
                String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
                String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
                String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

                textID.setText(id);
                textFirstName.setText(first);
                textLastName.setText(last);
                textJobTitle.setText(job);
            }
            else{
                rs.next();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            rs.first();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            textID.setText(id);
            textFirstName.setText(first);
            textLastName.setText(last);
            textJobTitle.setText(job);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            rs.last();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            textID.setText(id);
            textFirstName.setText(first);
            textLastName.setText(last);
            textJobTitle.setText(job);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Workers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

            String title = (args.length == 0 ? "CheckBox Sample" : args[0]);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test");
            panel.setBorder(border);

            javax.swing.JCheckBox[] jCheckboxArray;

            int CheckBoxNumber = 5;
            jCheckboxArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[CheckBoxNumber];
            for(int x = 0; x < CheckBoxNumber ; x++) {
                jCheckboxArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
                jCheckboxArray[x].setText("CheckBox " + x);
                panel.add(jCheckboxArray[x]);
            }

            Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setSize(300, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textFirstName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textID;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textJobTitle;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textLastName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected.
You have two frames in your code: `Workers` (which extends JFrame) is created in the first statement (3rd line) of the `main` method, and the frame you've created directly in the main method name just `frame`.
They both are shown when program starts.

What you probably want it to add your panel with checkboxes to the `Workers` frame. You can do this for instance in the `Workers` constructor, put after `initComponents()` your own code remembering that the frame you are operating on is `this` special variable (don't create another frame).
You need also to take into account already existing components on that frame in order to make it look good, moving the code most probably won't suffice.